# discord.js Check if user and bot are in the same voice channel

Tags: discord.js

I actually haven't found anything that worked in the last 30 mins.

When someone does a command, I want my music bot to check if it's in a voice channel AND if the bot and the user are in the same channel.

That was my latest try:

```js
if (
  bot.voiceConnections.get(
    bot.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id.channel.id !== 'undefined',
  ) &&
  bot.voiceConnections.get(message.guild.id).channel.id !==
    message.member.voice.channel.id
)
  return message.channel.send(
    '>>> :x: | You need to be in channel together with me.',
  );
```

Comment: do you mind putting the code in a codeblock?

Comment: Sorry, I placed the ``` wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user has a voice state and if that voice state is in same channel as you

```js
if (message.member.voice && guild.voice && message.member.voice.channelID === guild.voice.channelID) {
 // whatever next
};
```

Learn more about:
[GuildMember voice](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice)
[Guild Voice](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=voice)